# Is rice vinegar bad for my non-stick rice cooker?

Tags: vinegar, rice-cooker, teflon

I have a rice cooker with a detachable bowl with non-stick (I presume teflon) coating on the inside. It looks something like this:

[image: rice cooker bowl]

When cooking sticky ("sushi") rice, after the cooking is done, you are supposed to add rice vinegar to finish the rice. Is it safe to add the vinegar in the same non-stick bowl that I cooked the rice in? If possible I'd like to avoid having to do extra dishes.

Comment: All righty, if you want to answer the question, please post an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be fine.  The acidity of the vinegar would be an issue if it were to come into contact and react with bare metal.  Non-stick cookware is fine for, say, making tomato sauces, etc, which means the coating in not especially reactive to acidity, which makes rice vinegar okay.

As a confirming point, when I was walking through Costco yesterday, I saw the latest generation of automated rice cooker/food steamer, and it had a sushi rice setting on the new ones, so they are clearly okay for that purpose.